# Armadillo cross-compilled error linking with BLAS and LAPACK Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt, armadillo

I'm trying to cross-compile (from `ix86` to `ARM`) a code on the Eclipse IDE using the **armadillo** library.

I'm using the `arm-linux-gnueabihf` compiler from [linaro.org](https://www.linaro.org/).
I already set up everything on Eclipse and can sucessfully cross compile c++ code.

After following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263427/cross-compiling-armadillo-linear-algebra-library) I could generate the `liblapack.a`, `libf2c.a` and `liblas.a` cross compiled libraries.

I think I correctly linked on Eclipse:

> Cross G++ Linker -> Libraries ->
>
> Libraries (-l)
>
> lapack
>
> f2c
>
> blas
>
> Library Search Path (-L)
>
> Added the path to liblapack.a, libf2c.a and liblas.a files.

I can run simples code like the following without any problem. I think it's because simple programs like this don't need the cross compiled libraries, just the armadillo.

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
int main() {

mat A = randu(4,4);
cout << "A:\n" << A << "\n";
return 0;
}
```

But, when I try to compile my code with matrices multiplications or any other function that uses functionalities from the cross-compiled libraries, like this one:

```
#define ARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK
#define ARMA_USE_BLAS
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;
int main() {

mat A = randu(4,4);
mat B = randu(4,4);
cout << "A:\n" << A << "\n";
//Matrices multiplication
cout << A*B << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
'Building target: test'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'

arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"[path to the liblapack.a,liblas.a and libf2c.a files]" -o "test" ./src/test.o  -llapack -lf2c -lblas

./src/test.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemv<double>(char const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
[path to the armadillo library]\include/armadillo_bits/translate_blas.hpp:36: undefined reference to `dgemv_'

./src/teste.o: In function `void arma::blas::gemm<double>(char const*, char const*, int const*, int const*, int const*, double const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, int const*, double const*, double*, int const*)':
[path to the armadillo library]\include/armadillo_bits/translate_blas.hpp:62: undefined reference to `dgemm_'

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:45: recipe for target 'test' failed`
make: *** [test] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete
```

Very similar problem as in here : [Armadillo + BLAS + LAPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999416/armadillo-blas-lapack) , but on my case the compilation just crashes everytime.

I already cross-compiled another time the libraries to see if was this the problem and had no success.

Comment: Most probably a problem with the symbol mangling. The linker error shows a plain c (not mangled) symbol is missing. Take care when including plain c headers in c++ compilation units to enclose them within [`extern "C" { ... } `](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c) properly.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I'm newbie so I have to ask:
the plain c term that you are referencing in the Linker error is the `dgemm_' term?

Comment: Yup. This most likely appears because some units were compiled with the c++ compiler and others with the c compiler (or vice versa). The details are explained well in the linked duplicate (it has many sections, but I am confident you'll find it there).

Comment: Well this maybe can be the problem, but I really want to believe that a user of the armadillo library don't need to change the code in the "include/armadillo_bits/***.hpp" files. Anyway I will read all the answers from the linked duplicate I really want to learn how to make this work.

Comment: I can reopen the question now you have the link as a base for more research about the probable problem. Anyhow reopening gives others which have met the same problem and fixed it a chance to write an answer here.